# Make a variable equal to values from multiple cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel macro to create a new Excel tab ("Tracker") where changes made to any worksheet within the workbook are recorded, detailing "Cell Changed", "Old Value", "New Value", "Old Formula", "New Formula", "Time of Change", "Date of Change", and "User".

The macro will not detail the "Old Value" of the change where the target of the change are multiple cells, and instead shows as "Multiple Cells Selected" in the Tracker tab.

From what I can deduce, I need the declared variable "vOldValue" to equal a string created from the values from the selection.

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim sOldAddress As String
Dim vOldValue As Variant
Dim sOldFormula As String
 
Private Sub Workbook_TrackChange(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        sh.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "&06" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & vbLf & "&A"
    Next sh
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
     '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
     'lenze 2003(http://vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=909)
     'Colin_L 2009 (http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?t=376400&referrerid=76744)
     'Mark Reierson 2009 (http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=1074)

     '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
     
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wActSheet As Worksheet
    Dim iCol As Integer
    Set wActSheet = ActiveSheet
     
     'Precursor Exits
     'Other conditions that you do not want to tracke could be added here
    'If vOldValue = "" Then Exit Sub 'If you comment out this line *every* entry will be recorded
     
     'Continue
     
    On Error Resume Next ' This Error-Resume-Next is only to allow the creation of the tracker sheet.
    Set wSheet = Sheets("Tracker")
     '**** Add the tracker Sheet if it does not exist ****
     
    If wSheet Is Nothing Then
        Set wActSheet = ActiveSheet
        Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = "Tracker"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
     '**** End of specific error resume next
     
    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
     
    With Sheets("Tracker")
         '******** This bit of code moves the tracker over a column when the first columns are full**'
        If .Cells(1, 1) = "" Then '
            iCol = 1 '
        Else '
            iCol = .Cells(1, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column - 7 '
            If Not .Cells(65536, iCol) = "" Then '
                iCol = .Cells(1, 256).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1 '
            End If '
        End If '
         '********* END *****************************************************************************'
        .Unprotect Password:="Secret"
         
         '******** Sets the Column Headers **********************************************************
        If LenB(.Cells(1, iCol).Value) = 0 Then
            .Range(.Cells(1, iCol), .Cells(1, iCol + 7)) = Array("Cell Changed", "Old Value", _
            "New Value", "Old Formula", "New Formula", "Time of Change", "Date of Change", "User")
            .Cells.Columns.AutoFit
        End If
         
        With .Cells(.Rows.Count, iCol).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
             
            .Value = sOldAddress
             
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = vOldValue
            .Offset(0, 3).Value = sOldFormula
             
            If Target.Count = 1 Then
                .Offset(0, 2).Value = Target.Value
                If Target.HasFormula Then .Offset(0, 4).Value = "'" & Target.Formula
            End If
             
            .Offset(0, 5) = Time
            .Offset(0, 6) = Date
            .Offset(0, 7) = Application.UserName
            '.Offset(0, 7).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous 'Adds a line at the end of the row
        End With
         
         '.Protect Password:="Secret"  'Uncomment to protect the "tracker tab"
         
    End With
ErrorExit:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
     
    wActSheet.Activate
    Exit Sub
     
ErrorHandler:
     'any error handling you want
     'Debug.Print "We have an error"
    Resume ErrorExit
     
End Sub
 
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
     
    With Target
        sOldAddress = .Address(external:=True)
         
        If .Count > 1 Then
            
            vOldValue = "Multiple Cells Selected" '???? Change this to get value of each cell selected before the change ????
            sOldFormula = vbNullString
             
        Else
             
            vOldValue = .Value
            If .HasFormula Then
                sOldFormula = "'" & Target.Formula
            Else
                sOldFormula = vbNullString
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: There are more than one way to update multiple cells (eg. via copy/paste or by drag-filling) which would *not* get captured by this approach, even if you made the necessary modifications (you'd need to convert `vOldValue` and `sOldFormula` to arrays matching the size of the selection)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this Sub to retrieve the value and formula of one or more cells into string variables:

```vb
Public Sub ValueFormulaToString(rg As Range, _
    ByRef strValue As String, ByRef strFormula As String, _
    Optional delimiter As String = "|")
    
Dim c As Range, result As String

For Each c In rg.Cells
    If Not IsError(c.Value) Then
        strValue = strValue & c.Value & delimiter
    Else
        strValue = strValue & "Error" & delimiter
    End If
    If c.HasFormula Or c.HasArray Then
        strFormula = strFormula & c.Formula & delimiter
    ElseIf c.HasSpill Then
       strFormula = strFormula & c.SpillParent.Formula
    End If
Next

strValue = Left(strValue, Len(strValue) - Len(delimiter))
If LenB(strFormula) > 0 Then
    strFormula = "'" & Left(strFormula, Len(strFormula) - Len(delimiter))
End If

End Sub
```

Your  SheetSelectionChange-Event has to be updated

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
     
    With Target
        sOldAddress = .Address(external:=True)
        ValueFormulaToString Target, vOldValue, sOldFormula
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I replaced the SheetSelectionChange-Event, however I am getting a "Compile Error: Variable not defind for sOldValue. How should this variable be declared?

Comment: sorry - that's a typo - should be sOldFormula - I updated the answer

Comment: Updated the SheetSelectionChange-Event, but now the Compile Error is on the vOldValue, "ByRef argument type mismatch." Does this have to do with how the variable was previously declared?